# How to log warn only in log4j

Tags: java, properties, log4j, warnings

In Struts 2 application we use log4j for logging. I want to log only warn but when i try to use in my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout
```

it prints error and fatal log too. I want only warn log. I read the levels of log in some tutorials. So I know why error and fatal prints, because they are less priority than warn. How to print warn log only in my console?

My Java code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LogClass {

    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LogClass.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            log.trace("Trace");
            log.debug("Debug");
            log.info("Info");
            log.warn("Warn");
            log.error("Error");
            log.fatal("Fatal");
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to switch to XML configuration file instead of properties file?

Comment: @voicu,okay i will switch if i got the solution in xml configuration of log4j

Comment: I have the similar problem and I am using log4j2, how to apply LevelRangeFilter in log4j2 xml configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelRangeFilter.html) filter. Your XML configuration file could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    debug="false">

    <appender name="warn-out" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="warn.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMax" value="warn" />
            <param name="LevelMin" value="warn" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMax" value="warn" />
            <param name="LevelMin" value="warn" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="warn-out" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

For more options go [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/LogToAppenderByLevel).

It looks like properties file configuration does not support filters. The following is taken from log4j's official wiki:

> Filter is not supported by [`PropertiesConfigurator`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).

**EDIT**: Added console appender as well to the XML and turned off debug for log4j. Now it should go to both file and console.

Comment: prints log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [warn].
log4j: root level set to WARN
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.FileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [file] to [warn.log].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%m%n].
log4j: Setting property [levelMax] to [WARN].
log4j: Setting property [levelMin] to [WARN].
log4j: Setting property [acceptOnMatch] to [true].
log4j: Adding filter of type [class org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter] to appender named [warn-out

Comment: @Madhesh, have you checked the `warn.log` file though? :)

Comment: ,i use console appender so only i got the above error.i changed your answer to console appender.it's works for me.Thanks