# How to set the log4j configurations to only log info mesages

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In my log4j configurations xml file i want to create a separate log file for only including info level messages. So i have set the configurations as below :

```
 <Appenders>
    <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/admin-web-error.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/admin-web-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="activity-log" fileName="${log-path}/admin-web-activity-log.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/admin-web-activity-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="hms.apptizer.admin.controller" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="error-log" level="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="activity-log" level="info"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

activity-log is the file I want have these info messages. Right now I'm getting error and debug level messages too. How can I configure this ONLY to include the info messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log warn only in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052623/how-to-log-warn-only-in-log4j)